# Menu hover submenu - longer time

Tags: javascript, css

I want to increase the freezing timing for the sub-menu to stay same when I `mouseover` it. 
Here's my `code`:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul id="subnav" class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li style="width: 16.6666666666667%">
        <li style="width: 20%">
            <a style="width: 16.6666666666667%" href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li style="width: 20%"><a style="width: 16.6666666666667%">Corporate Information</a><div class="sub-menu" style="overflow: hidden; display: none;">
            <div class="menuInnerLeft"><span>Transforming Care Bringing Health to Every Home 1</span></div>
            <div class="menuInnerRight">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a class="subNavItem" href="http://www.juronghealth.com.sg/We_Are_JurongHealth/Our_Vision_Mission_Value.aspx" target="_blank">Vision, Mission &amp; Values</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="subNavItem" href="http://www.juronghealth.com.sg/We_Are_JurongHealth/At_the_Helm.aspx" target="_blank">Board &amp; Senior Management</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we have your code in fiddle.

Comment: i have some questions: 1. Do you use Bootstrap? 
2. Could you post your code with a css file? It makes it more readable.

Comment: Can you please provide a **working example** using Embeded StackOverflow Snippet or at best JSFiddle (or put your code online elsewhere) so we could test it? It's really hard to tell what's going wrong without being able to see your code.

Comment: yes i  m using bootstrap but I am not using the structure as it does not support the layout i wanted to achieve.

Comment: Let me add on. The problem i faced is when I try to move my mouse out from the first level of navigation to my sub-menu, the sub-menu will just gone.... cant move my mouse cursor over. ...... anyone got solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
      $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(200);
    }, function() {
      $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(200);
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Jquery hover:second parameter which is the function to use when you leave the element:

```
$(".menu_item").hover(
    function(){},
    //When hovering the item: stuff

    //When You leave the item:
    function(){
        //Leave duration time:
        var duration = 500;
        setTimeout(function(){}, duration );
    }
);
```

Or benefit the jquery stop() function.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I am currently using this... is there anything wrong"?;

Comment: $('ul.nav>li').hover(
  function(){
   subMenuLength = $('.sub-menu', this).find('a').size();

  function delayedAlert() { timeoutID = window.setTimeout(slowAlert, 20000);
  }
    
   if (subMenuLength > 0){
 
     $('.sub-menu', this).slideDown(300);
     $(".sub-menu").delay(800).fadeIn(400);
     $(".sub-menu").setTimeout(slowAlert, 20000);
     //$('.sub-menu', this).show();
    }else{
     $('.sub-menu', this).hide();
    }
   },
   function(){
    //hide its submenu
    //$('.sub-menu', this).hide();
    var duration = 500;
    setTimeout(function(){}, duration );
   }
  
  );